# Как поменять блоки разных родителей местами?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Можно ли при такой структуре поменять местами при маленьких экранах блоки 2 и 3?

```html
<container>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>3</div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     <div>2</div>
     <div>4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как насчет? (нажмите `Развернуть фрагмент` и поизменяйте ширину экрана)

```css
.div-1 { background-color: #eeeeee; }
.div-2 { background-color: #dddddd; }
.div-3 { background-color: #cccccc; }
.div-4 { background-color: #bbbbbb; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<container>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="div-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">1</div>
    <div class="div-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">2</div>
    <div class="div-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">3</div>
    <div class="div-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">4</div>
  </div>
</container>
```